# Functions php, make drop down list work

Tags: wordpress, function

In functions php, this works like a charm:

```
<textarea name="menu1anchor" id="menu1anchor" cols="40" rows="1"><?php echo get_option('menu1anchor'); ?></textarea>
```

How can i make this drop down list work? I want to be able to input my values and select a desired one later on.

Right now, it does not matter which value I select, after i press "save changes" it does not send my value thru the form to wordpress options.

```
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
     <option value="1">Microsoft</option>
     <option value="2">Google</option>
     <option value="3">Apple</option>
     </select>
```

Thank u!

Comment: something like... <option value="1" <?php echo (1 == get_option('menu1'))?"SELECTED":""; ?> >Microsoft</option>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name="menu1" id="menu1">
     <option value="1"<?php selected(get_option('menu1'),1); ?>>Microsoft</option>
     <option value="2"<?php selected(get_option('menu1'),2); ?>>Google</option>
     <option value="3"<?php selected(get_option('menu1'),3); ?>>Apple</option>
     </select>
```

Try that instead.

Comment: It works, this is the second really cool code you made for me;) Where should i send the beer?:) 

Will it work if i try this?

<option value="testvalue"<?php selected(get_option('menu1'),'testvalue'); ?>>Microsoft</option>

I just love coding wordpress, even if I'm a newb, you should see some interesting codes i did... I'm a webmaster, but would love to become a wordpress coder someday:)

Comment: That will work. The way the `selected()` function (and `checked()` and `disabled()`) works is, if both arguments are equal, it echoes the code necessary to make the option selected (or checked, or disabled).